# Register user CRUD actions and others

Tags: codeigniter, events, web, model-view-controller

I need register all activity into my webapp, for example when an user delete,add or edit some record and the specific events. Any ideas? I'm use codeigniter for programming.

Like GLPI for example:

[GLPI Events Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpRcA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Make a model called activity and create a log method:

`$this->activity->log("{$this->curr_user->name} logged in.");`

I personally use short-codes and a switch statement (which can get pretty unwieldy if you have a lot of activities - not sure if recommended):

`$this->activity->log('page_access', array('uri' => uri_string()));`

or

`$this->activity->log('modified', array('table' => $table, 'id' => $id));`

Here is my activity model:

```
class User_activity_model extends CI_Model {

    /**
     * Admin-only log types
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    private $admin_types = array('page_access', 'user_registered', 'logged_in', 'login_failed', 'login_failed_sa');

    /**
     * Main user activity logging function
     * 
     * @param string $action
     * @param array $arr Additional attributes per case
     * @return void
     */
    public function log($action, $arr = array()) {
        switch ($action) {
            default:
                return;
            case 'backup_created':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} created a backup {$arr['filename']} at {time}.";
                break;
            case 'backup_restored':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} restored backup {$arr['filename']} at {time}.";
                break;
            case 'user_registered':
                $msg = "{$arr['first_name']} {$arr['last_name']} registered with username: {$arr['username']}.";
                break;
            case 'added':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} added item {$arr['id']} to the {$arr['table']} table.";
                break;
            case 'modified':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} modified item {$arr['id']} in the {$arr['table']} table.";
                break;
            case 'deleted':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} deleted item {$arr['id']} from the {$arr['table']} table.";
                break;
            case 'published':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} published item {$arr['id']} from the {$arr['table']} table.";
                break;
            case 'unpublished':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} unpublished item {$arr['id']} from the {$arr['table']} table.";
                break;
            case 'logged_in':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
                $msg = "{$username} logged in at {time} from IP {$ip}.";
                break;
            case 'login_failed':
                $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
                $msg = "Someone tried to login with username {$arr['username']} at {time} from IP {$ip}.";
                break;
            case 'login_failed_sa':
                $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
                $msg = "Someone tried to login with social auth provider {$arr['provider']} at {time} from IP {$ip}.";
                break;
            case 'page_access':
                if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
                    $identity = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                } else {
                    $identity = "Someone (IP: {$this->input->ip_address()})";
                }
                $msg = "{$identity} tried to access a page they didn't have permission for: {$arr['uri']}.";
                break;
            case 'logout':
                $username = $this->curr_user->details()->username;
                $msg = "{$username} logged out at {time}.";
                break;
        }
        $data = array(
            'action' => $action,
            'type' => in_array($action, $this->admin_types) ? 'admin' : 'all',
            'message' => $msg
        );
        $this->add_info();
        $this->db->insert('user_activity', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Adds identifier information to the insert query
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_info() {
        $this->db->set('time', 'NOW()', false);
        $this->db->set('ip', $this->input->ip_address());
        if (!empty($this->curr_user->id())) {
            $this->db->set('user_id', $this->curr_user->id());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates log array
     * 
     * Format:
     * 
     * array(
     *       [date]
     *             array(
     *                   [0] = message1
     *                   [1] = message2
     * 
     * @param boolean $admin_only Show all logs?
     * @return boolean|object Logs object, FALSE otherwise
     */
    public function get_logs($admin_only = true) {
        if (!$admin_only) {
            $this->db->where('type !=', 'admin');
        }
        $this->db->order_by('time', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('user_activity');
        if ($query->num_rows() < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        $rows = $query->result();
        $data = new \stdClass();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            // replace {time} with timezone converted time
            $time = $this->timezone->convert($row->time);
            $row->message = str_replace('{time}', $time, $row->message);
            // date Y-m-d acts as key for messages on that day
            $key = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($time));
            $data->{$key}[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Truncates user_activity table
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function delete_logs() {
        return $this->db->truncate('user_activity');
    }

    /**
     * Stub for automate hook to add 'added' activity
     * 
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function automate_activity_add($data) {
        $this->activity->log('added', array('table' => $data['table'], 'id' => $data['id']));
    }

    /**
     * Stub for automate hook to add 'modified' activity
     * 
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function automate_activity_modify($data) {
        $this->activity->log('modified', array('table' => $data['table'], 'id' => $data['id']));
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]